# How to save data from input file, in to dictionary array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I working with multiple file input, and I want to save in to dictionary array values from file input.

For this I created a script:

```
var imageArray = [];

$(document).on("click", ".attach-img", function () {
    $('#imgupload').click();
    $("#imgupload").on('change', (event) => {
        value = event.target.files[0].name;
        var imageLink = `<a href="${window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])}" target="_blank">${value}</a><i class="fa fa-remove image-remove"></i>`;
        imageArray.push({ id: liId, imageName: value, imageLink: imageLink });
    });

});
```

but after each clicking of the button, it's duplicating array values.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are always using the same file `files[0]` 

Comment: @Viney how can i make it's correct?

Comment: Anytime you select a file it triggers a change event on the file control which will always remove whatever selection was there earlier

Comment: Your description is quite unclear. One obvious gotcha from your code though: *never attach events from possibly repeating events*. Here, everytime you click on `.attach-img`, a new event will be added, resulting in multiple event handlers attached to your input all firing at each change.

Comment: @Kaiido and how i can fix it?

Comment: The clarity of your decription? Through an [edit]. For the event handling, simply don't add this event from inside the other event handler. Hard to tell better without any idea why you did so to begin with.

Comment: @Kaiido i attach codepen link, and you can check all script https://codepen.io/qunzorez/pen/yLNBJVq

Comment: Add all relevant code to the question itself, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.